# c# Crystal report .NET object as Data source

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I m using .net Object as my crystal report data source and its working very well 
but I cannot find some properties such as List or any container .

```
public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public _Client Client { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<Modules.Accessoires.Accessoire> Products { get; set; }
    public int AcessoireID { get; set; }
    public string TotalPrice { get; set; }
}
```

The report shows only the ID , Date , AccessoireID, Total Price how can i manage to use the others ?

Answer (score 0):

To do the list:

```
1. Modules.Accessoires.Accessoire maa = new Modules.Accessoires.Accessoire();
2. List<Modules.Accessoires.Accessoire> lst = new List<Modules.Accessoires.Accessoire>();

then 
3.for example maa.id =1002 and maa.name = "sample name";
4. lst.Add(maa);
5. Order or = new Order();
6. or.Products = lst;
```

Good Luck